# SQL Query using Group by 4

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tables which looks like below. 
Employee table

```
Date        Employee ID   Employer ID     Salary
2/3/2011      10            20            45666
3/12/2009     43            53            2356
```

Employer Table

```
Employer ID     State
53                OH
42                MI
```

Trying to get the total salary by month and by state using group by clause. But not getting the results. what am i doing wrong?? any help appreciated

```
select date, sum(salary) from employee
group by to_char(date,'MON')

select sum(salary) from employee A, Employer B
where A.employer id=B.employer id
group by B.state
```

Also i need to get the top 10 distinct employee ids based on their salary

```
select DISTINCT employee id from employee
where rownum<=10
order by salary desc
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: vikdor nice job with the editing! are you a moderator?

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов When you reach 2k points of reputation you can edit posts and answers. Now (currently i got 400+) I can edit but need approval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to group by the exact expression in your select list, e.g.,

```
select to_char(date,'MON'), sum(salary) 
  from employee 
 group by to_char(date,'MON');
```

You probably want to include the state in your second query:

```
select b.state, sum(salary) 
  from employee A, Employer B  
 where A.employer_id=B.employer_id  
 group by B.state;
```

Generally speaking, stating in your question that you're "not getting the results" is not very helpful to the folks you're asking help of. Please provide any error messages or output that describes what "not getting the results" means.

Comment: thanks DCookie. It works!! and will definitely type the error messages in future.